# Opencv installation error: cannot see opencv_core247.dll

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, installation

I looked into bunch of tutorials to how to install OpenCV for Visual Studio10 and added all the *d.lib files and all the without d.lib files but it still gives error saying opencv_core247.dll is missing (which I 'm sure I added) so the program cannot be started. In order to solve this problem reinstall the program.

I was having missing pdb files and I solved it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412851/visual-studio-2010-cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file)

Now I'm getting

```
KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16()Unknown 
msvcr110.dll!__CxxThrowException@8()Unknown
opencv_core247.dll!51385535()Unknown
```

errors also.

so what do you recommend for me to do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. What you must be missing is adding the opencv library path to your system PATH variable in windows. This issue has been answered earlier in many related posts.
Go to Start->Computer->System Properties->Advanced system settings->Environment variables
In System variables, scroll down to Path.
Double click and add in the "Variable value" field, at the end add
;C:\Path to opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin

(The above is for 64 bit windows and Visual studio 10. Change the path accordingly for your machine and VS version)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I had changed the Path variable also... after trying everything I saw in Internet still couldn't find anything I tried asking here:/

Comment: @Ege I recently spent hours on this problem myself. For starters, try copying the dll file from OpenCV installation directory to your project's Debug folder (or Release folder, depending on whether you are using Debug or Release mode).That should work, but its not a good long-term solution. 
Also, one mistake I made was to use a space between the last valid entry and the new entry when editing the Path variable. Make sure there are no unnecessary spaces  when you add to the Path variable.