# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Cannot find or open the PDB file- McAfee

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, mcafee, attach-to-process

I am trying to debug my C++ program in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010- having just recompiled the code after making some changes,  have run the program, and am now trying to attach to the process (Debug -> Attach To Process...).

However, when I do this, I am presented with an error that I've never seen before:

> 'AMSCDNUSimulatord.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee\Host Intrusion Prevention\HcApi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>
> The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1c04) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I haven't done anything differently to what I normally do (built the project, copied the 'AMSCDNUSimulatord.exe' (debug executable for my program) from the workspace to the release folder of the program- overwriting the existing .exe file), run the program, and attached to process from Visual Studio's Debug menu.

This usually works with no problems at all- but for some reason, I'm now getting the above error in Visual Studio's console... Anyone know anything about this?

I haven't changed any configuration of McAfee or anything, so can't think why it would be complaining about that.

I have tried checking the "Microsoft Symbol Servers under Symbol Locations" as suggested in answer to: [Visual Studio 2010 "Cannot find or open the PDB file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412851/visual-studio-2010-cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file), but this doesn't seem to have made any difference.

With regard to the set up of my project, the source is in the folder `C:\Workspace\Simulator`, and that is where the .exe file is placed when the project is built. I am then running the release from `C:\workspace\release\Simulator`, so I copy the .exe from the first folder to the second once it's built, and run it from there. The thing is, that I've been following that method exactly for months, and never had any problems running the program and attaching to the process before, so I doubt that the issue is anything to do with the change to that I've made to the code... but how/ why would McAfee now be preventing me from attaching to the process?

Comment: Does this prevent debugging? Usually failing to load symbols just makes stack traces that involve the module in question less accurate.  Also, does uninstalling McAfee fix the problem? If so, you may want to change the AV you use (or talk to McAfee about fixing the problem).

Comment: Yes- it does prevent debugging- I also get the following line in the console after the one quoted above: `The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1c04) has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

Comment: How exactly does it "prevent" debugging *your* code ? Are you unable to set breakpoints, line-step, animate, etc (*your* code) ? The message you posted should not preclude you from debugging your modules; it simply means call information for *that* module is not available. You would experience a similar message for the MS OS modules were you not wired to their symbol server, and even then, it would not prevent you from debugging *your* debuggable modules with their appropriate pdb files matching.

Comment: You are just seeing your anti-malware infecting your program.  Microsoft is not going to provide you with the PDB for another company's executable.  Just don't bother, you don't want to debug McAfee code.  Focus on your own.